# Twitter, oauth and coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, twitter, oauth

I am trying to post to twitter. I have the app already authenticated and now want to post an update.

This is what my http post is at:

```
<cfhttp url="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json" method="post">
 <cfhttpparam type="header" name="status" value="#urlEncodedFormat('my test post')#" />
 <cfhttpparam type="header" name="oauth_consumer_key" value="xxx" />
 <cfhttpparam type="header" name="oauth_nonce" value="xxx" />
 <cfhttpparam type="header" name="oauth_signature_method" value="#urlEncodedFormat('HMAC-SHA1')#" />
 <cfhttpparam type="header" name="oauth_token" value="xxx" />
 <cfhttpparam type="header" name="oauth_timestamp" value="#GetTickCount()#" />
 <cfhttpparam type="header" name="oauth_version" value="1.0" />
</cfhttp>
```

Has anyone done this? Am I going down the right route?

Comment: GetTickCount() returns in milliseconds, api expects seconds, so don't forget to div 1000.

Comment: Someone has written a CFC for use with Twitter. Have you had a look at that? http://twittercomponent.riaforge.org/

Comment: Andy, not offering a solution but an observation: your code above shows use of #urlEncodedFormat('HMAC-SHA1')#, but that seems to indicate a misunderstanding. The arg to that function is a URL to be formatted, and while it takes a 2nd argument to indicate a charest, that would not be a valid one. Hope the other pointers to possible solutions have helped. Did you ever resolve things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you read this?

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth#auth-request

you need to construct the "signature base string" and post as body (warning: untested code, for CF8+)

```
<cffunction name="makeSignatureBaseString" returntype="string" output="false">
  <cfargument name="httpMethod" type="string" required="true">
  <cfargument name="baseUri" type="string" required="true">
  <cfargument name="values" type="struct" required="true">

  <cfset var signatureBaseString = "#httpMethod#&#URLEncodedFormat(baseUri)#&">
  <cfset var keys = StructKeyArray(values)>
  <cfset var key = "">

  <cfset ArraySort(keys, "textNoCase")>
  <cfloop array="#keys#" index="key">
    <cfset signatureBaseString &= URLEncodedFormat("&#key#=#values[key]#")>
  </cfloop>

  <cfreturn signatureBaseString>
</cffunction>
```

-

```
<!--- using values from http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth#auth-request --->
<cfset params = {
  oauth_consumer_key = "GDdmIQH6jhtmLUypg82gる",
  oauth_nonce = "oElnnMTQIZvqvlfXM56aBLAf5noGD0AQR3Fmi7Q6Y",
  oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1",
  oauth_token = "819797-Jxq8aYUDRmykzVKrgoLhXSq67TEa5ruc4GJC2rWimw",
  oauth_timestamp = "1272325550",
  oauth_version = "1.0"
}>

<cfhttp url="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json" method="POST">
 <cfloop collection="#params#" item="key">
   <cfheader type="header" name="#key#" value="#params[key]#">
 </cfloop>

 <!--- add status to the params for makeSignatureBaseString() --->
 <cfset params.status = "setting up my twitter 私のさえずりを設定する">

 <cfhttpparam type="body"
   value="#makeSignatureBaseString('POST', 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json', params)#">
</cfhttp>
```