# Issue in generating oauth_signature for twitter in coldfusion

Tags: api, twitter, coldfusion, twitter-oauth

I have started twitter API testing while creating an `OAuth` signature the response showing is

> {"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}

Added all the params and headers mention in the doc, and not getting the correct result, please let me know if  i am doing anything wrong.

```
<cfset status = "Hello Ladies + Gentlemen, a signed OAuth">
<cfset include_entities = true >
<cfset oauth_consumer_key = "x3OgJNjJ5TPGj7jyvLz9rUzfU">
<cfset oauth_nonce = createUUID()>
<cfset oauth_signature_method ="HMAC-SHA1" >
<cfset oauth_timestamp   = GetTickCount()/1000>
<cfset oauth_token   = "1196333045885702145-BPWGfPyKakezuqYoLaYXiIgQ5TWAkf">
<cfset oauth_version   = "1.0">

<cfset parameterString = "include_entities=true&oauth_consumer_key=#oauth_consumer_key#&oauth_nonce=#oauth_nonce#&oauth_signature_method=#oauth_signature_method#&oauth_timestamp=#oauth_timestamp#&oauth_token=#oauth_token#&oauth_version=1.0&status=#urlEncodedFormat(status)#" >
<cfdump var="#parameterString#">

<cfhttp url="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json" method="POST" >
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="mimetype" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="*/*" />
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Connection" value="close" />
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Host" value="api.twitter.com" />
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="User-Agent" value="OAuth gem v0.4.4" />

  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Length" value="76">
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="include_entities" value="#include_entities#">
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="oauth_consumer_key" value="#oauth_consumer_key# ">
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="oauth_nonce" value="#oauth_nonce#">
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="oauth_signature_method" value="#oauth_signature_method#">
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="oauth_timestamp" value="#oauth_timestamp#">
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="oauth_token" value="#oauth_token#">
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="oauth_version" value="#oauth_version#">
  <cfhttpparam type="header" name="status" value="#urlEncodedFormat(status)#">

 <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#parameterString#"   >
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#cfhttp#"><cfabort>
```

Comment: ok, so what have you done to look at investigating this issue? When stepping through and debugging this what are you sending, what else are you getting back with this error.

Comment: This is somewhat old, but might prove useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081437/twitter-oauth-and-coldfusion

Comment: No I have tried this but I could not find the issue

Comment: Have you tried with this Have you tried with this https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update, Do you need to mentioned the `oauth_signature` that's missed in your above code. Please check with that.

Answer (score 2):

use this method, it would work correctly

```
<cfset consumerKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
    <cfset consumerSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
    <cfset bearerToken = ToBase64(consumerKey & ":" & consumerSecret)>
    <cfset authorization = "Basic " & bearerToken>
    <cfhttp url="https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token" method="post" charset="utf-8" >
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="#authorization#">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8">
        <cfhttpparam type="body" value="grant_type=client_credentials">
    </cfhttp>
```

Comment: yes its working but the token is not working for ouath, i am referring https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/log-in-with-twitter/guides/implementing-sign-in-with-twitter

Answer (score 2):

Refer this and Create your developer account on twitter,by your own key, ouath will work.refer this [create secret key for oauth](https://brianflove.com/2014/08/20/twitter-sign-in-using-oauth-and-coldfusion/)